# How to save more than 1 value on Radio Button to Json type data ? Laravel 5.8

Tags: json, laravel

I have an input question answer, and this answering true or false using radio button like this

> it is question 1 -----------------------------------(*)----( )

> it is question 2 -----------------------------------( )----(*)

> it is question 3 -----------------------------------(*)----( )

In my problem, I can't save all radio, just 1 radio can detect like this

```
       Environment & details:
GET Data empty
POST Data
text1   
"Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel ,pastikan tidak ada yang terkelupas"
input1  
"false"
text2   
"Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan"
input2  
"true"
text3   
"Periksa kondisi pencetakan (tinta dan kertas printer)"
input3  
"true"
text4   
"Fix and squish bugs"
input4  
"false"
alat_id 
"1"
_token  
"buno7LyZ9PLaq3ByKpDYlNz0TuaagV8HPbhqznT8"
name    
"post"
```

It's my 1 problem; my second problem is: how can I input data to DB using a format like =

> {"question 1":"true","question 2":"false","question
> 3":"true","question 4":"false","question 5":"true"}

This question I need to input manually but the answer is from form input.

This is my view #edit; I have a fault on "value", I just put 1 value on the first form.

```
<form class="form-group" action="/user" method="post">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Tidak Baik</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Baik</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td><input style="border:none" type="text" name="text1" value="Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel ,pastikan tidak ada yang terkelupas"></td>
      
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input1" value="false" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input1" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td><input style="border:none" type="text" name="text2" value="Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan"></td>
      
          <td>
              <label><input type="radio"  name="input2"  value="false" checked></label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <label><input type="radio"  name="input2" value="true"></label>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.</td>
      <td><input style="border:none" type="text" name="text3" value="Periksa kondisi pencetakan (tinta dan kertas printer)"> </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input3"  value="false"  checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input3" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.</td>
      <td> <input style="border:none" type="text" name="text4" value="Fix and squish bugs"> </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input4"  value="false" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input4" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="alat_id" value="1">        
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
  </tbody>
 
</table>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="post">Submit</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

This is my controller, my problem is how to save {'text1':'true','text2':'false',.......}

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = 1;
    $user->question = $request->{"question1":"input1","question1":"input2","question1":"input3";// this line i dont know how to do 
    $user->catatan = "empty";
    $user->status = "every week";


    $user->save();
    dd($user);
    // return view('dashboard');

}
```

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: i think you need to set you radio input name with array example : `name="radio_name[]"` and make all the radio name same with this you can get all the answers in array

Comment: if the radio button nmae is same , its cant choose more than one choosed .

Comment: I wanna ask does each question have one answer or multiple ?

Comment: just 1 answer . like . Question 1: true . only can choose 1 . sir this question for saving data is solved . not using [] , but in my form my "value : true or false" just on form number 1

Comment: but i have a new problem , i dont know how to saving this form

Comment: i update my question sir